# To create or not to create

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge

$\hskip2.5in$Crossword format.
$\hskip2.5in$Zorn's lemma;
$\hskip2.5in$Spain.

$\hskip2.5in$Programming language.

$\hskip2.5in$The fourth;
$\hskip2.5in$A conditional.
$\hskip2.5in$Jack and the Beanstalk.
$\hskip2.5in$Sinister beliefs.

[image: talk]
$\hskip2.5in$Do you think the same?

Comment: *To be, or not to be!*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Some puzzles certainly are!

What's being said:

> **PUZZLES ARE DIFFICULT**

Crossword format, Zorn's lemma, Spain:

> **PUZ**: Popular crossword software [Across Lite](http://www.litsoft.com/across/alite/download/) uses the **.puz** format 
>  **ZL**: Zorn's lemma in short 
>  **ES**: [Two letter code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) for Spain

Programming language:

> **ARE**: [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) programming language

The fourth, A conditional, Jack and the Beanstalk, Sinister beliefs:

> **D**: The fourth letter 
>  **IF**: A conditional 
>  **FI**: from the Giant's "[fee, fi, fo, fum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fee-fi-fo-fum)" 
>  **CULT**: one might have sinister beliefs

Comment: By the way, (ROT13) VS pna nyfb or [ovpbaqvgvbany](http://www.mathwords.com/i/if_and_only_if.htm), gbb ;D